# Routing in a hybrid app that is classic ASP.Net web forms and MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

i have inherited an application that is both clasic asp.net web forms and mvc (started as web forms project). I would like to setup routing like MVC. What is the best way to go here? **All i need is a push in the right direction.**

I know how to setup routing for the MVC only project via global.asa > App_Start > Route Config and area registration cs files.

Environment:

VS 2012, IIS 7, ASP.NET 4.0, classic asp.net web forms and MVC 4.

My thinking:

I am thinking about doing some thing like following, do you guys see an issue here? I may end up with some web.config issues but at this this time i am not sure what those would be. **I need your advice to properly setup the structure here.**

Global file addition:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {

            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

App_Start > RouteConfig.cs

```
    namespace My.Site
    {
        public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new string[] { "My.Site.Controllers" }
                );

OTHER ROUTES WILL GO HERE, THESE MAY REDIRECT TO a webform page or to a controller action. 

            }




        }
    }
```

Comment: I have found a good example here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc Do you agree with my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the following to setup all properly.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX